# How to add individual elements of an object in an Arraylist through a for loop?

Tags: object, arraylist, element

I am trying to add all elements of an object into ArrayList. elements of the object are of different type.

e.g. object Employee having attributes like emp_id,name,address,DOB.

I want to store each attribute as an object in an ArrayList. Like,

```
ArrayList[1] = Employee.emp_id
ArrayList[2] = Employee.name
ArrayList[3] = Employee.address
```

I want to do it dynamically. Like, in future more attributes are added in this object, without doing a manual work. Is there a way to create an array List?

Comment: if you don't know the number of fields, you can go using reflection to add all the fields. More info about reflection see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html)

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList must be of the same type. You can have an ArrayList of type  in which you can do what you are doing, since all objects in Java extend Object. If you are trying to store different Object types in an arraylist, however, this is not possible.

You may know that first part, just was a little unclear in your post.

Here's how to do it with objects using reflection:

```
//make sure you import java.lang.reflect.*

public void addMyFields(Employee e){
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList();
    for (Field field : emp.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
    {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        list.add(field.get(emp);
    }    
}
```